# How can I put CSS and HTML code in the same file?

Tags: html, css

I'm a profane in CSS, I don't know anything about it. I need to put HTML code and the CSS formatting for it in the same string object for an iPhone program.

I have the HTML code and the CSS code, but I don't know how to mix them together. Could you help me?

The HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" href="./exemple.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
</head>
<body>
    <p>
    <span class="title">La super bonne</span>
    <span class="author">proposée par Jérém</span>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS styles:

```
.title {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: bold;
    text-size: 1em;
}

.author {
    color: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .title {
        color: blue;
        text-decoration: bold;
        text-size: 1em;
    }

    .author {
        color: gray;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
    <span class="title">La super bonne</span>
    <span class="author">proposée par Jérém</span>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

On a side note, it would have been **much** easier to just do [this](http://www.google.co.uk/search?source=ig&hl=en&q=include+css&oq=include+css&aq=f&aqi=g10).

Answer (score 6):

You can include CSS styles in an html document with `<style></style>` tags.

Example:

```
<style>
  .myClass { background: #f00; }

  .myOtherClass { font-size: 12px; }
</style>
```

Comment: Does it matter where these tags are inside the document itself? EDIT: never mind, found the answer: `Internal styles are defined within the <style> element, inside the <head> section of an HTML page` [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're looking for? You place you CSS between `style` tags in the HTML document header. I'm guessing for iPhone it's webkit so it should work.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .title { color: blue; text-decoration: bold; text-size: 1em; }
    .author { color: gray; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
    <span class="title">La super bonne</span>
    <span class="author">proposée par Jérém</span>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Or also you can do something like this.

```
<div style="background=#aeaeae; float: right">

</div>
```

We can add any CSS inside the **style** attribute of HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

There's a style tag, so you could do something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .title 
  {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: bold;
    text-size: 1em;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options:
1, add css inline like  style="background:black"
Or
2. In the head include the css as a style tag block.